# Show that $\frac{x+2}{x-2}$ is a one-to-one function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Problem : Show that $\frac{x+2}{x-2}$ is one-to-one function, i.e show that for any $x,y \neq 2$ such that $\frac{x+2}{x-2} = \frac{y+2}{y-2}$, that necessarily $x=y$.

Comment: Assume that $\frac{x+2}{x-2} = \frac{y+2}{y-2}$.. what can you say about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: As a tip, start with the definition: what does it mean for a function to be one to one? What are some properties of functions that imply the function is one to one?

Comment: "I don't know how to solve this question:"  Why not?  Show that if $\frac {x+2}{x-2} = \frac{y+2}{y-2}$ then that would mean $x = y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{x+2}{x-2} = \frac{y+2}{y-2} \implies (x+2)(y-2) = (y+2)(x-2) $

$\implies xy -2x+2y -4 = xy-2y+2x -4 \implies 4x = 4y \implies x = y$.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of one-to-one:  If $f(x) = y$ then $x$ is the *only* element in the domain so that maps to $y$.

That means if $f(x) = f(w) = y$ then $x =w$.

So if $\frac {x+2}{x-2} = \frac {y+2}{y-2}$ then we must prove $x = y$.

Can we do that?

If $\frac {x+2}{x-2} = \frac {y+2}{y-2}$ then....

> $(x+2)(y-2) = (y+2)(x-2)$ and so...

.

> $xy + 2y - 2x - 4 = yx + 2x - 2y -4$ and so...

.

> $2y -2x = 2x - 2y$ and so....

.

> .... fill in the blank.....

.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer:  the composition of one to one functions is one to one.

$\dfrac{x+2}{x-2}=a(b(c(d(x)))),$ where $a(x)=1/x, b(x)=1-x, c(x)=4/x, $ and $d(x)=x+2.$